# Query time is slow on Tableau Hyper extracts

Tags: database, google-bigquery, tableau-api

I'm using tableau with a bigquery data source that has 500M rows, 30 columns. In order to have this BQ data used by my workbooks I refresh an extract (hyper) every day.

In my workbooks I have 6 parameters and one filter that is a user filter.
I notice that the workbooks loading time is slow. It gets also slow when I change the values of parameters.
When using performance recording I get numbers of 40s per query.
While reneding time is in the order of milliseconds.

Is this normal even if I'm using extracts with less quick filters ? How could I enhance the performance of querying ?

*Tableau Server info : I'm using Tableau 2022.1 on a 2 nodes server with 256Gb Ram.*

Comment: What times do you get if you query the BigQuery source directly rather than using an extract. It isn't immediately obvious that an extract would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

How many marks are you pulling into the Dashboard? If it is a summary query /Dashboard, it shouldn't take this long. More the number of marks you pull out, higher will the time taken. Also, user filters could also be a problem. Try removing that to see the impact.